# Replace 00 with 20 in years in date field in Postgres/Rails

Tags: postgresql

I have a lot of dates where the year is 0015 instead of 2015 or 0016 instead of 2016, etc, etc...

I could probably write a script in ruby to take care of it for me but there is a lot of entries and I think that script would take too long.

Is there some way I can do this in SQL?

I'm willing to run the script 17 times to do all of the 2000's if I can only do it year by year.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is column type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these are date or timestamp fields, you ought to be able to do it as a simple `UPDATE` query.

First, we can find all the affected dates with something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column < '0020-01-01';
```

Assuming this returns the right rows, we can simply add 2000 years to each affected date:

```
SELECT my_column as old_value, my_column + interval '2000 years'
FROM my_table WHERE my_column < '0020-01-01';
```

Assuming this all looks right, apply it to the table:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET my_column = my_column + interval '2000 years'
WHERE my_column < '0020-01-01';
```

Comment: Duh.. jeez can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks IMSoP great answer, exactly what I was looking for.